# Prometheus grouping by label

Tags: prometheus

I have a Gauge with labels no and type.Let's say my some metrics are:

```
dbValues{no="10",type="invoice"} 1
dbValues{no="054017843",type="archive"} 1
dbValues{no="0562447",type="receipt"} 1 
dbValues{no="10",type="archive"} 1
```

I want to group these metrics by their no.Is there a possible way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count do the following:

```
count by (no) (dbValues)
```

If you want to sum do the following:

```
sum by (no) (dbValues)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, count seems good but when I count by no I can't acces the type, I want to group by no and also acces type label values

Comment: Maybe you want "count by (no, type)" or just "count by (type)". Test these options and tell if they solve your issue.

Comment: With count by (no, type) it doesn't show the correct value, and I have some other metrics that I don't want to goup by but I want to monitor. With count and sum I can't see those metrics.